# Rotation deleting bug in mobile Android app (Samsung S3 Neo)

Tags: bug, android-app

I was editing an answer of mine on the official Android app. After I wrote a paragraph or so, I rotated my phone by accident and... everything that I wrote until that point was deleted, gone.

I could not find a way to get it back in my answer.

When first writing an answer a stub is saved, so no big deal. This should be fixed mainly when editing.